# Gremlin vertex programs / graph computers using Gremlin.Net?

Tags: c#, gremlin, olap

Are vertex programs / graph computers supported by Gremlin.Net?
Or is it only supported on JVM Gremlin implementations?

Comment: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-drivers-variants

Comment: @HadoopMarc I have read this specific section of the page link twice with no luck. Maybe I need help. Plz, if you spotted the answer direct me to it. Yes, they talk about embedded systems, but are vertex programs . graph computers considered embedded? Can they be sent over the wire to a remote server from C# client?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why the votes to close the question?! It is a yes/no question that can be answered with a citation form the docs. For example, @HadoopMarc has cited the docs. I just could not find it myself.

Comment: @JonasH I have edited the question to be specific for Gremlin.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a `VertexProgram` in Gremlin.NET. Those must be written in Java. You could however execute that JVM-written `VertexProgram` with .NET if you submit a script with your traversal referencing that program. There is an example of that approach [here with more details](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#pagerankvertexprogram), but I'll paste some code here:

```
gremlin> result = graph.compute().program(PageRankVertexProgram.build().create()).submit().get()
==>result[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:0],memory[size:0]]
gremlin> g = traversal().withEmbedded(result.graph())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:1,label:person,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.11375510357865541,name:marko,age:29]
==>[id:2,label:person,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.14598540152719106,name:vadas,age:27]
==>[id:3,label:software,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.3047200907912249,name:lop,lang:java]
==>[id:4,label:person,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.14598540152719106,name:josh,age:32]
==>[id:5,label:software,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.17579889899708231,name:ripple,lang:java]
==>[id:6,label:person,gremlin.pageRankVertexProgram.pageRank:0.11375510357865541,name:peter,age:35]
```

Comment: Thx for passing by. How do you reference the vertex program from the passed script in .Net?

Comment: the example above is executed in Gremlin Console, but you would basically just send a script of that `graph.compute()` line. You would of course need to ensure that the jar containing your custom `VertexProgram` is in Gremlin Server's classpath so that you can reference it in your script.